# External Stylesheet not working

Tags: html, css

I have added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://blogsoc.org/mail1/style.css/" />
```

in the index.html above  tag. But my stylesheet is not working. my style.css code is:

```
body
{
background-color: #23314F;
}

main
{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 880px;
background: #FAFAFA;
}
```

What changes should be made?

Comment: Could you post some more of the html. I don't think it's in the css but more where you have placed it in your html.

Comment: Is main an id or a class? If it is an id it should be `#main` or if it is a class it should be `.main`.  Please post your html that goes with this.

Comment: There's no tag above. Is the css file linked correctly? What's the `class` or `id` for you main content? Replace `main` with `#main` or `.main`.

Comment: Oh yes. Earlier it was #main but I removed the # for testing purpose. Now working as I have removed the extra "/" from the end... Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link provided is incorrect

```
href="http://blogsoc.org/mail1/style.css/
```

must be

```
href="http://blogsoc.org/mail1/style.css
```

without last `/`

Answer (score 1):

Not too much discriptiv question.
But try removing last slash.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://blogsoc.org/mail1/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

"Not working" is a very vague description of the problem.

The only obvious issue is that `main` will select `<main>` elements which do not exist in HTML. We can't tell you what to change it to because can't see your HTML. I recommend reading [selectutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/).

Since the question has been updated:

`http://blogsoc.org/mail1/style.css/` gives me a 404 error. You need to provide a working URI to your stylesheet. `http://blogsoc.org/mail1/style.css` appears to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem before.  And I solved it.  The problem was that I originally declared my page as a `<frameset>` in Eclipse.  Even when I changed it, the problem persisted.  I copy and pasted the page and tested in different browsers.

The source page was linking to the stylesheet on the browser perfectly.  It was just not showing the style on my page.

I created a new page with no declaration and it works.

```
The `<link>` tag was not the problem.

    <html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test Title</h1>
this is a test page.
</body>
</html>
```